# How to copy directories and their subdirectories by using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy directories and their subdirectories from C: to D: with same name, but any of folders' name must not change.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command in your batch file

```
XCOPY source [destination] /E
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But I want to delete old directory (:C\) I tried to use del command for it like this: "del source \E" but it does not work. Can you help me for delete old directories?

Answer (score 0):

xcopy might help you

```
xcopy /E c:\name d:\name
```

Comment: If you want to delete recursivly, you may use del /S c:\name

Comment: I tried your command line, but it delete only all txt files which are in the subfolders but, I want to delete all folders in parent folder. this command line: "rd /s /q c:\Temp" solved my problem. Thank you for your answer.